# Converting string - different encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I have file with hex string:

```
ff  00  d8  00  ff  00  e0  00  18  20
```

I cannot find a way to convert it to:

```
ff  d8  ff  e0  91
```

As you can see

> ff 00

becomes

> ff

and

> 18 20

becomes

> 91

What encoding should I use in java to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the question? How to transform the String `"ff  00  d8  00  ff  00  e0  00  18  20"` to `"ff  d8  ff  e0  91"`?

Comment: How to transform ff 00 into ff ... 18 20 into 91 using encoding mechanism...

Comment: @Nikola have you tried using `Charset` and `CharsetDecoder` (mentioned in an answer) classes?

Comment: I have a similar string and a similar problem. 91 is half or 182 but I don't see how that's relavent.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate encodings by using `Charset` and `CharsetDecoder` interfaces from `java.nio.charset` package.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetDecoder charsetDecoder = charset.newDecoder();
```